# Doing Mahalanobis Metric Learning on a Per-Population Basis?

Tags: machine-learning, distance-functions, metric

I have a dataset that consists of pairs $(x,y)$, with:

- $x$ being a high dimensional vector of personal features (e.g height, weight etc) of individuals; the individuals belong to one of three different types of populations: young, middle-aged and old people.
- $y$ is their performance on some task (e.g, scoring a goal), $y\in \{{\pm 1\}}$

Since the populations are inherently different from one another, the same set of features can express differently. As an illustrative example, in the middle-aged group height could be an advantage (correlated with positive label) where in the old group, it could be a disadvantage (correlated with negative label).

My goal is to learn a *task-specific* similarity metric. That is, learn a mapping  $d: X \times X \rightarrow [0,1]$ s.t $d(x_1,x_2)\approx 0 $ if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both good at scoring goals (regardless of which population they come from).

I am considering using the popular form of **Mahalanobis distance learning** using similarity and dissimilarity constraints, as suggested by my labeled data (example reference [here](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume10/weinberger09a/weinberger09a.pdf)).  To address the fact I have different populations, I thought about learning the matrix $M$ that specifies the metric on a *per-population basis*.

My questions:

1. Using this approach, I have a measure of similarity for any two individuals belonging to the *same population*. BUT: How do I calculate the similarity between two individuals from *different* populations?
2. Are there any other suggested approaches that might make sense in this scenario?

Any relevant references, articles, reading material etc will be highly appreciated.